# Обособление слова "интересно"

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится ли запятая перед  словом "интересно" в следующем примере:
"Это когда(,) интересно?".

"Интересно" - это, насколько известно, не вводное слово. Возможно здесь соединены два предложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь не два предложения. Интересно - действительно не вводное слово. Оно выступает в качестве наречия и предикатива.

```
интере́сно
   I нареч. качеств.
    Возбуждая интерес I 3., любопытство; занимательно.

   II предик.
    1.
    Оценочная характеристика ситуации, чьих-либо действий как возбуждающих интерес I 3., привлекающих внимание.

       Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.
```

***Именно в значении предикатива в вашем примере выступает слово ''интересно'' и, следовательно, отделяется запятой.***

Answer (score 4):

> Ставится ли запятая перед словом
>   "интересно" в следующем примере: "Это
>   когда(,) интересно?".

Если поставите запятую, будет восприниматься как вводное.

Из ***"Словаря вводных слов" О.А. Остроумовой и О.Д. Фрамполь:***

[image]

=====================================================================

> "Это когда, интересно?"

На мой взгляд, предложение простое, **неполное**, осложнённое вводным.

Контекст мог бы быть примерно таким:

> *-- Мне казалось, что мы тут немножко отдохнём.*
>
> *-- **Это когда, интересно, [мы тут сможем отдохнуть]?** У нас, мой дорогой, 
>   неделя. На всё про всё…*

Функция у слова *интересно* в выделенном **жирным** предложении -- вводное слово.

Comment: Спасибо Вам всем Огромное!

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае для того, чтобы определить, нужна ли запятая, нужно знать, что этой фразой хотят сказать - запятая меняет её смысл.

a) Вариант без запятой. Это может быть вопрос с попыткой угадать ход мыслей собеседника. Например:

- Знаешь, в каких случаях люди у телевизора забывают о времени?
- Это когда интересно?

б) Вариант с запятой. Смысл вопроса совершенно иной: это выражение недоверия собеседнику или удивления сказанному.

- Я же перевел на твой счёт обещанные деньги.
- Это когда, интересно?

Во втором случае интонация предполагает речевую паузу (более или менее выраженную). И разделяет она две части фразы: вопрос "**это когда?**" (первая часть) и краткое выражение того, что интересует ответ на этот вопрос "**(мне) интересно (знать)**". Будь эти части в краткой или полной форме (они могут быть и в другой последовательности), они должны разделяться знаком препинания:

Это когда, интересно?

Интересно, это когда?

Мне интересно (знать): это когда?

Это когда (мне интересно знать)?

Это когда? Мне интересно (знать).

Comment: Могу добавить ещё одно:

== Это когда, интересно мне знать?

Здесь "интересно мне знать" я бы рассматривал как вводное предложение.

Comment: В моем тексте контекст - согласно второму варианту (б), пишу с запятой.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Интересно, когда это? (в вашем случае, скорее всего неправильное составление предложения, на своем мнение настаивать не буду, т.к. не лингвист)