# "Интересно(,) как?"

Tags: запятые, части-речи

Вот пример из головы:

> — А я вчера сам научился собирать кубик Рубика!
>   — Правда?! Интересно(,) как?

В [этом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/48261/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE) вопросе Серж говорит, что "интересно" предикатив, который обособляется. То есть получается, что несмотря на то, что придаточное из одного союзного слова не требует запятой, последняя нужна из-за слова "интересно". *Или всё-таки есть иное объяснение и аргументы в пользу её отсутствия?* Замечу, что я при первом рассмотрении был уверен, что она не нужна, да и сейчас не очень бы хотел её ставить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) ***ИнтерЕсно, (а) кАк***?

(2) ***Интересно кАк?***

Интонация первого варианта представляется мне более подходящей.

Пояснение

1) Итак, говорящий может выбрать любой вариант, но при постановке запятой делается пауза, а ударение падает на оба слова.

Такое решение соответствует правилу Розенталя (п. 4.3), где также говорится о двух вариантах: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

Запятая не ставится: 3) если придаточная часть состоит **из одного союзного слова** (относительного местоимения или наречия): Я бы тоже желал знать почему (Л. Т.);

В условиях контекста возможна **постановка запятой** или тире и перед одиночным союзным словом: Что же надо делать? Научите, что — **усиленное логическое выделение местоимения;**

2) А теперь о самом слове ***интересно***. Это слово может быть: а) обстоятельственным наречием (*он всегда рассказывает интересно*); б) предикативным наречием (*интересно, о чем он рассказывает*, это СПП).

**Примечание. Почему СПП?** Например, Грамота.ру так считает.

Сравнить: Вопрос № 301886.    Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в предложении: "**Интересно**, жаль ли ей собаку(,) или она рада?".

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Союзы ли…или рассматриваются в **сложноподчиненных предложениях** как повторяющиеся, а потому придаточные части сложноподчиненного предложения, связанные этими союзами, разделяются запятой: Интересно, жаль ли ей собаку, или она рада?

В нашем случае это именно СПП, так как имеется союзное слово ***как***.

3) Слово *интересно* быть **и вводным, но скорее его можно отнести к вводным безличным предложениям,** о которых говорит Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=124#pp124

Но в этом случае или **отсутствует союзное слово**, или слово *интересно* находится в **середине** предложения: *Что мы, интересно, об этом знаем? Интересно, это только мы об этом не знаем?*

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили!

Answer (score 3):

Приведенная вами фраза в зависимости от значения допускает два варианта пунктуационного оформления.

***— Правда?! Интересно, как (каким образом. предикатив)?***

***— Правда?! Интересно как (любопытно,  возбуждая интерес. нареч.)!***

В данном случае вариант с запятой представляется более верным. Обратите внимание на восклицательный знак во втором примере.

Comment: *Спасибо, Серж!*